# how to use ocx control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, controls, ocx

i need to use ocx control in my web application ..
please tell me how to use it

Answer (score 1):

using .OCX in ASP.NET web forms - technical discussion - developer ...

http://www.developerfusion.com/forum/thread/45749/

How to use ocx

http://forums.devarticles.com/asp-development-3/how-to-use-ocx-4894.html